# Check if Local User account exists and create it if it doesn't exist

Tags: command-line-arguments

I'm trying to write a command line script that will check if an local user account exists and create that account if it doesn't.

I have the two commands, but I want to put it together into a conditional check.

Command to check if the account exists.

```
Net user | find /i "Username"
```

Here's the command to create the account.

```
NET USER Username {Password}  /EXPIRES: NEVER /ADD
```

Also, I'm having problems with the /Expires switch working. When I check the account's settings it doesn't have "Password never expires" as checked.

Answer (score 1):

The /Expires switch is for the account, not the password. Try running this from PowerShell.

```
$user = "User3"
NET USER $user "Good1!PW" /Add 
Set-LocalUser -Name $user -PasswordNeverExpires $true -UserMayChangePassword $false
```